# React native how to parse from json

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to parse a json file with the code below and i cant get it to work, nothing is displayed.

I wanted to display some exhibits the title and their picture.

In the processExhibit i'm trying to get the json String with info and records and then map the records.
Any help is appreciated.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, FlatList, Image } from 'react-native';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';



 const processExhibit = results => {
  const processed = {
    info: {
      next: results.info.next
    },
    records: results.records.map(r => ({
      ...r,

      id: r.objectnumber
    }))
  };
  return processed;
};

class FetchExample extends Component {

  constructor (props: {}) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        isLoading: true,
        dataSource: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount () {
    const url =
            `https://api.harvardartmuseums.org/object?apikey=83bc8170-51ae-11ea-ac7c-97706fd5f723` +
            `&fields=objectnumber,dated,century,division,primaryimageurl,title` +
            `&sort=totalpageviews` +
            `&page=1` +
            `&size=44` +
            `&hasimage=1` +
            `&sortorder=desc`;
    fetch(url)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
        const results = processExhibit(responseJson);
        this.setState({
          isLoading: false,
          dataSource: results
        });
        results = processExhibit(responseJson);
        console.log("Before Change", JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result)));
      });
  }

  renderItem = ({item, index}) => {
    let { info, records } = item;

    if (!records[0]) return null;
    let details = records[0];

    return (
      <View >
        <View >
          <Text >{details.title}</Text>
          <Text >{details.century}</Text>
        </View>

        <View >
          <View >
            <Text >{ details.dated }</Text>
          </View>

          <View style={{ justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
            <Image source={{uri: details.primaryimageurl}}
              style={{height: 50, width: 50}}/>
          </View>

        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }

  keyExtractor = (item, index) => {
    return index.toString();
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1}}>
        <FlatList
          data={this.state.dataSource}
          keyExtractor={this.keyExtractor}
          renderItem={this.renderItem}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

And this is the json

```
  info: {
    next:
      "https://api.harvardartmuseums.org/object?apikey=a40093f0-53ec-11ea-850a-fbf5bb8990ef&fields=objectnumber%2Cdated%2Ccentury%2Cdivision%2Cprimaryimageurl%2Ctitle&sort=totalpageviews&page=2&size=44&hasimage=1&sortorder=desc",
    page: 1,
    pages: 4794,
    totalrecords: 210916,
    totalrecordsperquery: 44
  },
  records: [
    {
      century: "19th century",
      dated: "1888",
      division: "European and American Art",
      id: 299843,
      imagepermissionlevel: 0,
      objectnumber: "1951.65",
      primaryimageurl: "https://nrs.harvard.edu/urn-3:HUAM:DDC251942_dynmc",
      title: "Self-Portrait Dedicated to Paul Gauguin"
    },
    {
      century: "19th century",
      dated: "1877",
      division: "European and American Art",
      id: 228649,
      imagepermissionlevel: 0,
      objectnumber: "1951.53",
      primaryimageurl: "https://nrs.harvard.edu/urn-3:HUAM:DDC231456_dynmc",
      title: "The Gare Saint-Lazare: Arrival of a Train"
    }
]
```

**UPDATE**

```
componentDidMount () {
    const url =
            `https://api.harvardartmuseums.org/object?apikey=83bc8170-51ae-11ea-ac7c-97706fd5f723` +
            `&fields=objectnumber,dated,century,division,primaryimageurl,title` +
            `&sort=totalpageviews` +
            `&page=1` +
            `&size=44` +
            `&hasimage=1` +
            `&sortorder=desc`;
    fetch(url)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
        let results = processExhibit(responseJson);
        this.setState({
          isLoading: false,
          dataSource: results
        });
        console.log("Before Change", JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result)));
      });
  }


  render () {
    console.log('data: ', JSON.stringify(this.state.dataSource))
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1}}>
        <FlatList
          data={[this.state.dataSource]}
          renderItem={this.renderItem}
          keyExtractor={this.keyExtractor}

        />
      </View>
    );
  }
```

Comment: In your render function before return can you try to print the data to make sure it is correct? `console.log('data: ', JSON.stringify(this.state.dataSource))`

On my cursory glance at your code, I can't seem to find anything that is obviously wrong, other than maybe the flatlist isn't being used correctly, or something else is preventing the data from being obtained?

Comment: Is the JSON valid? (is it surrounded by a single set of {} braces)?

Comment: The json is valid, i tried placing the console log but nothing is printed. Sometimes i get this error : Tried to get frame for out of range index NaN. Could it be because there are 42 records and its too many? this is the link to the json : https://api.harvardartmuseums.org/object?apikey=a40093f0-53ec-11ea-850a-fbf5bb8990ef&fields=objectnumber,dated,century,division,primaryimageurl,title&sort=totalpageviews&page=1&size=44&hasimage=1&sortorder=desc

Comment: Delete the flatlist out of render and try again. Update your post with the new render function (leave what you have, just post an update)

Comment: Also, put some debug statements (console.log) in processExhibit

Comment: What should i place instead of flatlist, also console.log('data: ', JSON.stringify(this.state.dataSource)) now prints something out

Comment: It seems that you reassign a value declared as const.
Could you please replace `const results = processExhibit(responseJson);` with `let results = processExhibit(responseJson);`

Comment: I just tried let results = processExhibit(responseJson); but with no success i still get the error : Tried to get frame for out of range index NaN.

Comment: why you use **processExhibit(responseJson);** here ?

Comment: It also seems that [data should be an array](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist#data), and you are passing an object instead. Try to replace `data={this.state.dataSource}` with `data={this.state.dataSource.records}` or `data={[this.state.dataSource]}` second seems to fit best to your implementation of `renderItem`

Comment: It was a mistake,i posted the update but it still doesnt work

Comment: I just did that Max and now i've got an error saying TypeError: undefined is not an object(evaluating 'record[0]')

Comment: You did the first option?

Comment: I tried both of them and i got the same error

Comment: Let's try the second option with an extra check for data source.
`if (!records[0]) return null;` to `if (!records && !records[0]) return null;`

Comment: can you share your code on expo ? and is this api working live so that I could check its working and help you ?

Comment: I've tried the second option and now i see that at the console.log('data: ', JSON.stringify(this.state.dataSource))  it prints data : []

Comment: Yes the api is working live but i dont know how to share the code on expo

Comment: Seems that I [managed to fix it](https://snack.expo.io/rJ2dyE2mL)

Comment: @GherghinaAndrei jus open expo and there you find the option of expo stack and paste ypu code there.  and share the url of the page with me .

Comment: Thank you!! but how do iterate through them cause thats my initial goal

Comment: [Here it is](https://snack.expo.io/Byu6JNn78)

Comment: Thank you so much!! @Max